# How to maximize (take derivative) of expectation involving binomial probability?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, optimization, maxima-minima

Here $k$ and $n$ are **fixed** positive integers.

I need to find the maximum of $f(x) = E[5\min(m, k) +\frac{kx}2]$ for $x$ between 0 and 10.

Here we have $m \sim Bin(n, 1-\frac x{10})$.

The problem here is that $x$ lies in the probability of the binomial random variable.

We can actually write $f(x)$ as a polynomial of $x$ but I'm wondering if there's a way to find the maximum in terms of a binomial coefficient or probability perhaps.

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't you first get the answer using that $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$, tell us that answer, and then ask if there is an easier way to get it?

Comment: Maybe the maximum is achieved by $x = 10\frac{n-k}{k}$ if $n \ge k$ and $x=0$ otherwise.

Comment: I want the answer in terms of $x$ and I conjecture that the value of $x$ that maximizes the above satisfies $P(Bin(n-1, 1-x/10) < n-k) = 1-k/n$ (I might have accidentally flipped one of the signs/variables). I can't prove this but by plotting for certain values of $k$ and $n$ it seems likely.

Comment: You want the answer in terms of $x$?

Comment: @mathworker21 - I think OP meant he wants the optimal (maximizing) value of $x$, which he can then presumably plug back into $f(x)$ to get the maximum value.  Anyway, long time no chat!  I've been very busy with a job search and then a job change.  I miss MSE.  :)  I wonder if your guess above jives with my informal "answer" below?

Comment: @antkam oh wow, I hope you found a new job and are safe and doing well. I will look at your answer now

Comment: @mathworker21 - Yes the search had a happy ending, and I started the new job a few days ago.  :)

Comment: @antkam I think I meant $10\frac{n-k}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

**Corrected 4/16/2020** -- while in bed, I came to the same conclusion also reached by River Li.  He scooped me and posted it first :) and also provided a detailed algebraic proof.  Full credits to him!  Here I will provide a less algebraic and more intuitive argument.

**Not a rigorous, nor full, solution** -- but perhaps some ideas that others can improve upon?

**Claim:** I think the maximum point happens when $P(\color{red}{Bin(n-1,y)} < k) = k/n$ for the case $k < n$.  (The case $k \ge n$ is trivial and maximized at $x=10$.)

Disclaimer 1: My "proof" for the claim is not quite rigorous.  Disclaimer 2: Even if the claim is true, I don't know how to get from there to the OP's desired answer, because solving $P(m < k) = k/n$ is itself non trivial.  Modulo these disclaimers, here's my...

**"Proof":** I find it easier to think about the problem in terms of $y = 1- \frac{x}{10}$, and the question becomes maximizing

$$g(y) = {f(x) \over 5 } = E [\min(m, k)] + k (1-y) = h(y) + k(1-y)$$

where $m = Bin(n, y)$. As the OP pointed out, $h(y) = E [\min(m, k)]$ is a complicated polynomial in $y$, and it is theoretically possible to differentiate it, then find its root (numerically?) etc.  However, that is tedious and (at least for me) does not lead to useful insights.

Instead consider a "richer" sample space where there are $n$ i.i.d. variables, $X_1, \dots, X_n$ each one $\sim Uniform([0,1])$.  The $m=Bin(n,y)$ trial can be interpreted as flipping $n$ i.i.d. biased coins, which can be defined in this space ("embedded" into these $X_j$ variables) by interpreting the $j$-th flip to be a success if $X_j < y$.

Now consider an infinitesimal increase $y \to  y+dy$.  What is the probability that such a $dy$ increase causes $m$ and/or $\min(m,k)$ to increase?  If so, by how much?

By ignoring higher order terms, clearly the probability that exactly one $X_j \in [y, y+dy]$ is $n \, dy$, and two or more $X_j \in [y, y+dy]$ is zero.  I.e. the probability $m$ increments by one is $n \, dy$, and bigger increments have zero probability.

**[Edit begins here]** Now, $m$ incrementing does not mean $\min(m,k)$ will increment -- the latter happens only if $m < k$ to begin with.  Consider the *trinomial* process dividing $[0,1]$ into three intervals $[0,y], [y, y+dy], [y+dy, 1]$ and let $A, B, C$ be the number of $X_j$'s in each interval respectively.  Then $m$ increments iff $B > 0$, and $\min(m,k)$ increments iff $B > 0 \cap A < k$.  Now, ignoring higher order terms:

$$P(B > 0 \cap A < k) = P(B = 1 \cap A < k) = P(B = 1) P( A < k \mid B = 1)$$

Meanwhile, conditioning on $B=1$ means we have a *binomial* process between $A$ and $C$, with $A+C = n-1$, so $A \sim Bin(n-1, {y \over 1-dy}) = Bin(n-1, y)$.  Therefore

$$P(B > 0 \cap A < k) = P(B = 1) P( A < k \mid B = 1) = n\, dy \times P(Bin(n-1,y) < k)$$

The above gives the probability that $\min(m,k)$ increments by one, while bigger increments have zero probability.

Since the increment (if it happens) is exactly one, the probability of the increment happening equals the increase in expected value.  I.e.

$$ {d \over dy} h(y) = n \times Prob(Bin(n-1, y) < k)$$

and the maximum happens when:

$$ 0 = {d \over dy} g(y) = n \times Prob(Bin(n-1,y) < k) - k \\
\iff Prob(Bin(n-1,y) < k) = {k \over n} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\square$$

Comment: Very nice! I like the start, letting $y = 1-\frac{x}{10}$ -- would have saved me a lot of time. Your 'answer' gives $y = 0$ if $n > k$. I wonder whether we can make your argument rigorous.

Comment: Actually, it might be close to rigorous. Also, if it is indeed true that the maximum occurs when $Prob(m < k) = \frac{k}{n}$, then that would be good evidence that the answer is not simple.

Comment: wait, the claim that $\frac{d}{dy}h(y) = n\times Prob(m< k)$ should either be false or easily provable

Comment: I'm getting $\frac{d}{dy}h(y) = \frac{1}{y(1-y)}E[\min(m,k)(m-ny)]$ from bashing. The RHS is not $n\times Prob(m<k)$.

Comment: @mathworker21 - re: your 1st comment, if $n > k$ then $0 < k/n < 1$ and so the answer cannot be $y=0$ (which $\implies m = 0 \implies P(m < k) = 1$).  perhaps i was not being clear?  re: your 4th comment, i'm not seeing how you can obtain that from bashing.  i tried to follow your deleted answer (i can see it after gaining 10k rep!) but i'm afraid i lost track...

Comment: I meant $k > n$. The point is that your final answer is wrong if $k > n$, but by looking at the sign of $\frac{d}{dy}g(y)$, we see that if $k > n$, we want $y=0$ (and looking at the sign of $\frac{d}{dy}g(y)$ says that what you found is indeed a maximum).

Comment: And where did you lose track? I just updated the indices in the first line. Everything else should be straightforward, but maybe I messed something up.

Comment: @mathworker21 - thanks, i can keep track now but i think you need to be more careful of the boundary terms.  e.g. the $j=0$ term has $y^j$ which will not be differentiated into a $y^{j-1}$.  also, at $y \to 1$, the $dh/dy \to 0$ but i think your expression $\to kn$...?

Comment: I don't think I need to be more careful, since, for $j=0$, we multiply by $j$. And we multiply by $n-j$ for $j=n$. So I think all is right. Why do you think $\frac{dh}{dy} \to 0$ as $y \to 1$?

Comment: good point re: multiply by $j$.  hmm...  anyway, $h = E \min(m, k)$ and $m \sim Bin(n, y)$.  As $y \to 1, m \to n, \min(m,k) \to k$ so my gut feel is that $dh/dy \to 0^+$.  Just imagine the case of $n = 1000, k = 500$.

Comment: There's an insanely tiny chance that $m < k$ for $y=.999$. And there's an even insanelier tiny chance that $m < k$ for $y=.9999999$, but what's relevant is not how tiny these two numbers are but how they compare to each other. I see absolutely no reason why the derivative should tend to $0$. And also, I think my calculations below are correct :)

Comment: I think the issue might be with your second bullet. Looking at it again, it looks completely false.

Comment: @mathworker21 - you were right, my original 2nd bullet was wrong.  instead, i needed to consider the trinomial process.  this is now fixed, but i fixed it 1+ hr too late -- i got scooped by River Li.  :)  i cant quite reconcile my argument with your deleted calculations, but perhaps River Li already did?  (i havent checked his calculations.)

Comment: I think it's just the case that my deleted calculations confirm your prediction, since something magically becomes $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The case $n \le k$ is trivial. In the following, we deal with the case $n > k$.

*Result*: $f(x)$ achieves its maximum at a unique $p$ (so $x = 10 - 10p$) with $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, p) < k) = \frac{k}{n}$.

Remark: @John Smith said the value of x that maximizes the above satisfies
$\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, 1 - x/10) < n-k)  = 1 - k/n$ ("I might have accidentally flipped one of the signs/variables").
If we replace $x$ by $10-x$ in his equation, it is the same as my result, i.e.,
$\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, x/10) < n-k)  = 1 - k/n$
is equivalent to $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, 1 - x/10) < k) = \frac{k}{n}$.

$\phantom{2}$

The details are given as follows.

Let $Y = \min(m, k)$ and $p = 1- \frac{x}{10}$.
We have, for $i \in \{0, 1, 2, \cdots, k-1\}$,
$$\mathrm{Pr}(Y = i) = \mathrm{Pr}(m = i) = \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i},$$
and
$$\mathrm{Pr}(Y = k) = \mathrm{Pr}(m\ge k) = \sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}.$$
We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y] &= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} i \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} + k \sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}  \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} i \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} + k \Big[ 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} \Big]\\
&= k - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (k-i) \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}.
\end{align}
So, we have
$$f(x) = \frac{kx}{2} + 5 \Big[k - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (k-i) \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}\Big].\tag{1}$$
By using $x = 10 - 10p$, (1) can be written as
\begin{align}
f(p) = 10k - 5kp - 5 \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (k-i) \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}.
\end{align}
We have
$$f'(p) = -5k - 5\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (k-i) \binom{n}{i} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i} (i - np).$$

To proceed, we need the following result. The proof is given later.

*Fact 1*: It holds that
\begin{align}
&n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-1-i}\\
&\quad +
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (k-i) \binom{n}{i} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}(i - np)= 0. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Now, from Fact 1, we have
$$f'(p) = -5k + 5n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-1-i}. \tag{3}$$
Clearly, $f'(0) = -5k + 5n > 0$ and $f'(1) = -5k < 0$.
Thus, $f(p)$ achieves its maximum at some $p\in (0, 1)$ with $f'(p) = 0$.

From (3), we have
$$f'(p) = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-1-i} = \frac{k}{n}. \tag{4}$$
In other words,
$$f'(p) = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, p) < k) = \frac{k}{n}. \tag{5}$$

Note that $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, 0) < k)  = 1$ and $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, 1) < k)  = 0$.
Since $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, p) \le k-1)$ (notice: $k-1 < n-1$) is strictly decreasing of $p$ (see [1]),
there exists a unique $p = p_0$ such that $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{Bin}(n-1, p_0) < k) = \frac{k}{n}$.
Thus, $f(p)$ achieves its maximum at $p_0$.

Numerical experiment: $n = 8, k=5$; From (4), $p_0$ is a real root of $\frac{3}{8}-15p^7+35p^6-21p^5 = 0$,
we get $p_0 \approx 0.5789766668$, $x_0 \approx 4.210233332$ and $f(x_0) = 31.82592210$;
We use Matlab *binornd* to generate random numbers $m$ from binomial distribution
and do numerical calculation for $f(x)$.

*Reference*

[1] [Monotonicity of the CDF of a Binomial Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314465/monotonicity-of-the-cdf-of-a-binomial-distribution)

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*: (2) is written as
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i} [p(n-i) + (k-i)(i-np)] = 0.$$
Maple tells that it is true. I will try to prove it by hand.

**EDIT** 2021/01/14

I gave a proof here: [Prove the identity $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i} [p(n-i) + (k-i)(i-np)] = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819371/prove-the-identity-sum-i-0k-1-pi-11-pn-1-i-binomni-pn-i)

Comment: +1  I was trying hard to find a similar algebraic proof to my (corrected) informal / intuitive argument, but I was not succeeding at all.  Nice job!

Comment: @antkam  Thank you. My solution involves complicated calculation. Maybe there is simpler approach to get the optimality condition (as you and  mathworker21 discussed $\frac{d}{dy}h(y)$).

Comment: Your complicated calculations lead to the same result as my informal argument, so maybe they are actually equivalent, i.e. my answer is the "simpler approach" you mentioned?  I don't know.  Anyway, I'm glad to see a rigorous (if complicated) proof of that same result.

Comment: @antkam Your argument is high level.