# Prove the identity $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i} [p(n-i) + (k-i)(i-np)] = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> **Problem**. Let $n > k \ge 1$. Let $0 < p < 1$. Prove that
> $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i} \Big[p(n-i) + (k-i)(i-np)\Big] = 0.$$

I needed to prove the identity, when I tried to answer a question
([How to maximize (take derivative) of expectation involving binomial probability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617701/how-to-maximize-take-derivative-of-expectation-involving-binomial-probability/3628201#3628201)).
Maple tells that it is true. Numerical evidences also support its validity.

Any comments and solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I just come up with a solution:

Let
$$f(k) \triangleq \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i} [p(n-i) + (k-i)(i-np)].$$
We have
$$f(k+1) = \sum_{i=0}^{k} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i} [p(n-i) + (k+1-i)(i-np)]$$
and
\begin{align}
f(k+1) - f(k) &= p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-1-k}\binom{n}{k} k(1-p) \\
&\quad + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i} (i-np)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
f(k+2) - f(k+1) &= p^{k}(1-p)^{n-1-(k+1)}\binom{n}{k+1} (k+1)(1-p) \\
&\quad + \sum_{i=0}^{k} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i} (i-np)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&f(k+2) - f(k+1) - (f(k+1) - f(k))\\ 
=\ & p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-1-k}\binom{n}{k} (k-np)\\
&\quad + p^{k}(1-p)^{n-1-(k+1)}\binom{n}{k+1} (k+1)(1-p)\\
&\quad - p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-1-k}\binom{n}{k} k(1-p)\\
=\ & 0.
\end{align}
Thus, we have $f(k+1) - f(k) = f(2) - f(1) = 0$ for any $k\ge 1$.
Thus, we have $f(k) = f(1) = 0$ for any $k\ge 1$. We are done.